# Wonky passport photo

Tags: passports, uk-citizens

My UK passport recently arrived and the picture isn’t straight. It’s around 85 degrees. If I travel with it will I be ok?

Isn’t my photo stored on a database?

Bear in mind I mostly use the e-Passport gates so I am not sure.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I was also surprised, I would share it but it has my photo so..

Comment: P.S. If you're curious, you can use a passport chip reading app (on Android; AFAIK Apple still do not allow apps to read passport chips on iOS) to see if the photo is correct on the passport chip.

Comment: Can you blur the photo and other sensitive details in order to upload the picture? I'm curious. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't try to travel using a passport with an improper photo. This is a good way to find yourself spending a very long time in a detention room in an airport, possibly in a foreign country.

Contact the [Passport Adviceline](https://www.gov.uk/passport-advice-line) on 0300 222 0000 as soon as possible to report the problem. The line is open Monday to Friday, 8am to 8pm and weekends and public holidays, 9am to 5:30pm.

You may find the complete [passport complaints procedure](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-passport-office/about/complaints-procedure) on the gov.uk web site.

Comment: "possibly in a foreign country": presumably *only* in a foreign country, since the UK authorities will probably be able to confirm that the passport is genuine even if the picture is "wonky."

Comment: The covering letter with your passport should ask you to "check your passport for any mistakes, and contact HMPO as soon a possible if any are found". Contact HMPO on the number given in the letter

Comment: That number would be 0870 521 0410. That should also work but the cost may be higher than the 03 number.